# How to integrate a path integral (just one path for starters)?

Tags: calculus, integration

The definition of a functional integral is (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_integration)

$$
\int G[f] df=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dots \int_{-\infty}^\infty G[f] \prod{df[x]} \tag{1}
$$

---

Suppose a path integral

$$
I[p]=\int \exp(i S[p]) Dp
$$

From the definition (1), it seems that the path must be parametrized by x?

A. Is this correct?

If so, we may write:

$$
I[p[x]]=\int \exp(i S[p[x]]) Dp[x]
$$

---

**Now, I want to integrate but, to start just over one path $p_1$. Also, for simplicity suppose $S[p]=x$.**

Then, from the definition of a functional integral, I get:

$$
I_{p_1}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(i x) Dp_1[x]
$$

B. What about $Dp_1[x]$? Does it just become $dx$? Why? (What would $Dp_1[x]$ become if $S[p]=x^2$?)

If so, then I get

$$
I_{p_1}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(i x) dx=2\pi \delta(0)
$$

C. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you remember back to the days of your path integrals in vector calculus? The path element $\mathrm{d} \vec{r}$ (At least in Stewart's Calculus) could be simplified by choosing a specific $\vec{r}(t)$ so that $\mathrm{d}\vec{r}(t) = \vec{r}'(t) \mathrm{d} t$. Of course it's not nearly that simple, but it's something to think about

Answer (score 1):

The path integral is a functional integral and can be over any measure (over any continuous function defined by a parameter). By this I mean, the function $p$ can be a function of $t$, or $x$ or any other parameter. $S[p]$ means that $S$ is a functional of $p$ where $p(x)$ (I have chosen x as a convention, it does not necessarily mean space) is a function. And the measure $Dp$ means that it is an integral over all possible functions $p(x)$. So if you choose one particular $p(x)$ it is not a path integral anymore, it is just a definite integral (where you have specified the path). So the path integral definition does not make any sense.